# PYTHON Decision Tree Visualization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to visualize tree decision classifier that i have applied to my data in pdf or png file. I tried visualizing with graphviz via the code below:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)

clf =tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=43)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydot 
dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph[0].write_pdf("tree.pdf")
```

But the procedure can not be completed. Once i got the error of running out of memory and for the second time i got the error "dot stop working". Due to this issues i wanted to have an idea about the tree by knowing where is left children where is right children or left children? thanks for any response and help

Comment: how many edges do you have ?

Comment: @CodeIsLife i am fairly new to decision tree. can you please let me know what do you mean by "edge"? I thought the errors can be because of number of samples that i have which is 128000. For each sample there are 2 features

Comment: how deep is your tree: levels count , nodes count ...

Comment: @CodeIsLife max_depth is 43.

Comment: please post your code especially do part raising this error

Comment: If there are just 2 features, it should be a very simple tree. Can you show all the error messages you see?

Comment: @zyxue this is the error that i get  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHk1l.jpg

Comment: @CodeIsLife i am getting the error shown above after running this line of codes: graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph[0].write_pdf("tree.pdf")

Comment: I see, so you are on windows. I don't know much about `dot.exe`, but it is another program irrelevant to Python. `pydot` is probably a wrapper around it. I used a linux version of `dot` before. You could do something like this `tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot')` instead, and use `tree.dot` directly. Or if you're good with Python, you could actually extract all the information you need from `clf` object. I have done something similar before, the heads-up is that the information stored in `clf` is not super intutive, you may need to do quite a bit of transformation.

Comment: @zyxue regarding use tree.dot, i had tried this one before "tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot') 
with open("tree.dot", 'w') as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)" but it failed. I mean after running in python it is fine. But when i put this command "dot -Tpdf tree.dot -o tree.pdf", this error comes up: "Error: : syntax error in line 1 near 'dot' .  I really don't know how to deal with this error.

Comment: You may not need `with open("tree.dot", 'w') as f:`. Otherwise, the file might be empty, which is why it complains syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error something like below:

```
Program terminated with status: -11. stderr follows: dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps.
```

Then to understand the tree, you can try to put it in a tree text format on screen like below:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_text

r = export_text(clf, feature_names=df_X_train.columns)
print(r)
```